# To create a Linux RT real-time system, which functions in the kernel should be cropped out?

Tags: linux-kernel, real-time

I am customizing a Linux real-time system using the Linux `6.4.0` kernel and `patch-6.4.6-rt8` patch. When running `make menuconfig`, which configurations should be turned off to improve real-time performance?The system mainly serves as a robotic arm controller.

The system at this time, using `cyclictest` to test the delay effect, it was found that the jitter is a bit high, with a minimum value of 2 and a maximum value of 39.

```
# cyclictest -t1 -p 80 -n -i 1000 -l 10000
# /dev/cpu_dma_latency set to 0us
policy: fifo: loadavg: 0.27 0.07 0.02 1/122 627

T: 0 (  577) P:80 I:1000 C:  10000 Min:      2 Act:    2 Avg:    2 Max:      39
#
```

Comment: your arguments for `cyclictest` do not work. `-n` is not a flag that exists in the [upstream source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/rt-tests/rt-tests.git/tree/src/cyclictest/cyclictest.c) of cyclictest. Did you mean `-N`? If so, these results would be **fantastic**

Answer (score 1):

None, in general. The realtimeness of your system is not dictated by the features it has, but whether you apply the -rt patchset or not, and whether you do design and run the software that needs to be a realtime task appropriately. The only thing within an -rt-patched kernel that'd increase latency would be a driver that has a prolonged critical section where it disables interrupts, but, that would probably not fly with in-kernel drivers for most devices, and also, removing that driver would disable a hardware component that is actively being used. So, I don't think that's an option here.

Since your handle is "ABeginner", I'll allow myself the broad recommendation that you shouldn't be building your own kernel config from scratch, but use the -rt kernel with the `oldconfig` from your Linux distro, or if it supplies one, use the distro-supplied -rt kernel.

> The system at this time, using cyclictest to test the delay effect, it was found that the jitter is a bit high, with a minimum value of 2 and a maximum value of 39.

These numbers seem OK, within the boundaries of a modern x86_64 or aarch64 system. You say "jitter is a bit high"; but as an engineer involved in real-time signal processing: "a bit high" is not really a thing. Either your maximum latency is OK, or it's not OK. That's what real-time systems are about.

So, either you come to the conclusion that 39 µs is good enough (and it really might be! For anything audio-related, for example; or it might not be, say, for a machine emergency stop controller), or it's not – but then I'd ask you why you're doing a `nanosleep` accuracy test (and not something handling a hardware timer interrupt in kernel space, for example). That would really lead a little far here, I guess – it would involve figuring out which cores you pin to your realtime application process (if there's any such process, but then again, you're measuring userland `nanosleep`, so there has to be one), how they relate to your source of events, and what is in the chain between the source of events (assuming it's not just a timer) and your system acting on the event. So, sadly, all the hard things about improving real-time systems apply to Linux just as much as to much more bare-bone operating systems like FreeRTOS.

Comment: Thank you for your serious reply. The Linux environment I have built (with RT patches added) is for the `ethercat` master station, and the communication cycle is within 4ms. Can I receive more professional help from you regarding this?

Comment: You're always free to ask more question posts here on Unix.SE :) But I'm not experienced at all in ethercat or its latency requirements.

Comment: note that 4ms is 100× longer than the maximum latency you observe here. As I'm not experienced with this topic, I don't know whether that really is a problem – it just sounds to me it isn't.